# Example of haskell-mpi scatterSend and scatterRecv

Tags: haskell, mpi

does anyone have an simple example of [haskell-mpi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-mpi) scatterSend and scatterRecv.  I've looked at the example included in the package, but couldn't get a good enough understanding based on just that one example.

Thanks!

Comment: I would bug the maintainer, especially since haddocks aren't being generated for their package

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Simple API? There are more straightforward versions of those functions there.